# Apps for Office

Tags: office365, office-js

I wanted to have some clarification on Office add-ins deployment. The questions I have are as below:

1. If we install add-in via Office 365 Admin central , and the add-in started getting visible in all the browsers for the office online but was not getting displayed in the desktop Word application ? Is this is an issue with the centralized deployment model or there is some latency for the add-in to be visible ?
2. Is there no provision to close the add-in from the task-pane in Excel online , what I just see only option for minimizing the add-in which is not the case in Word and PowerPoint online.
3. After Installation of an add-in from office store in word online through chrome, and it was not visible in other browsers. Is it expected ?

Comment: How is this related to programming ? Please contact the Office 365 support.

Answer (score 1):

1. If it's showing on Word Online but not Word desktop then it could be because of the version of the Word desktop client. Users need to be on build 16.0.8067 or later
2. I believe Excel Online does act differently from PowerPoint and Word in that regard
3. It shouldn't be if the user was signed in when acquiring the add-in on chrome and signed in with the same account on other browsers